# How to change repository origin to new server in LAN?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

The problem I have is as follow:

The place I am working at brougth a new (very basic) server to replace the old one and they assigned me the task to set it up. I basically copied everything from the old server to the new one and installed all the programs.

The problem is that the old server works as our git repository where we push the changes of our projects and we want to move that to the new server too, but we don't want to lose the history or the option to revert to a previous commit, basically what I need to do is move the repository to the new server with everything.

So far I have not found anything similar to my situation and what I found is a bit confusing as I am very new to git and sourcetree.
Not sure if it is important but we plan to change the Ip of the new server to the Ip of the old one when we put it to work officially and the new server has the same folder structure as the one with the same name for the partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the nature of your Git server (Apache, SSH, GitLab, ...)
In your case, maybe BitBucket server

At minimum, you need to make bundle ([`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle)) of each of your repos: that way you only have to copy one file per repo (less risk of copy error that way)

But if your Git server is more complex than just repo (ie, if it has wiki, issues, ...), you will need to follow the backup process specific to that server. (Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31550230/6309) for GitLab, for instance)
For BitBucket: [Migrating Bitbucket Server to another server](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/migrating-bitbucket-server-to-another-server-776640406.html).